# Android 3D Java Open source game engine that supports OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

We are developing a 3D tool in Java on Android, and it is required that the tool uses OpenGL ES 3.0 because it's for an application for next gen devices. We would like to know if there is indeed a solution available, or if we will have to take an existing 2.0 solution and modify it.

Comment: GLES 3 is generally a strict superset of GLES 2.  An engine written for 2.x will work on 3.x, so modifying an existing solution would only be necessary if there were specific features you wanted to take advantage of.

Answer (score 3):

Android devices don't support hardware acceleration for OpenGL ES 3.0. You'd better use 2.0 solution.

Comment: There are only rumors that Android will support OpenGL ES 3.0. There are some GLES 3.0 Qualcomm demos showcased on HTC One phone (the one with dragon spitting flames) and they use some custom engine.